How can the custom thread-based monitoring affect the start time of celery tasks?
I'm using flask with celery to build my backend apis.
To prevent tasks running too long, I implemented a custom thread-based monitoring class to monitor tasks and stop them if they run for too long.
This is my implementation.
import os
import sys
from flask import Flask
from celery import Celery, Task
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
from celery.signals import setup_logging, task_prerun, task_postrun
import time
from datetime import datetime
import threading

CELERY_WORKER_POOL = 'prefork'
CELERY_WORKER_CONCURRENCY = 2
soft_time_limit = 1200
check_interval = 90

if CELERY_WORKER_POOL == 'prefork':
    # fix torch CUDA error
    # this forces the application to use spawn instead of fork
    os.environ["FORKED_BY_MULTIPROCESSING"] = "1"
    if os.name != "nt":
        from billiard import context
        context._force_start_method("spawn")
    # this can prevent pytorch model initialization hanging
    # not needed with worker_pool='threads'
    os.environ['OMP_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'

# Ensure Flask app context for Celery tasks
class ContextTask(Task):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with app.app_context():
            return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
            
def make_celery(app):
    # Configure Celery to use Redis as the broker
    celery_app = Celery(
        app.import_name,
        backend=DATABASE_URL,
        broker=REDIS_URL,
        include=[
            'apis.my_api',
        ]
    )
    celery_app.conf.update(app.config)

    # Set the worker processes
    celery_app.conf.update(
        worker_pool=CELERY_WORKER_POOL,
        worker_concurrency=CELERY_WORKER_CONCURRENCY,
    )

    celery_app.Task = ContextTask
    return celery_app

app = Flask(__name__)
celery_app = make_celery(app)


class LongRunningTaskError(Exception):
    pass

class TaskMonitor:
    def __init__(self, task_id, timeout=soft_time_limit):
        self.task_id = task_id
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.stop_event = threading.Event()
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.monitor)
        self.thread.start()

    def monitor(self):
        while not self.stop_event.is_set():
            end_time = time.time()
            duration = end_time - self.start_time
            if duration > self.timeout:
                # Revoke the task
                if CELERY_WORKER_POOL == 'prefork':
                    celery_app.control.revoke(self.task_id, terminate=True, signal='SIGTERM') # cannot be used with worker_pool='threads'
                self.stop_event.set()  # Stop the monitor after sending the alarm
            time.sleep(check_interval)  # Check every check_interval

    def stop(self):
        self.stop_event.set()
        self.thread.join()

task_monitors = {}

@task_prerun.connect
def task_prerun_handler(task_id, task, *args, **kwargs):
    task_monitors[task_id] = TaskMonitor(task_id)

@task_postrun.connect
def task_postrun_handler(task_id, task, *args, **kwargs):
    if task_id in task_monitors:
        task_monitors[task_id].stop()
        del task_monitors[task_id]

I thought when a task is received, the TaskMonitor.monitor starts at a new thread and won't affect the start time of tasks in the celery queue.
However, the fact is, if I set check_interval as 90 seconds and CELERY_WORKER_CONCURRENCY as 2, and I send 4 API requests at the same time, then the first 2 tasks will be executed immediately.
Although the first 2 tasks are done quickly (< 1 second), the remaining 2 tasks still start execution after 90 seconds, which is equal to the check_interval.
If I use time.sleep to let the task execution run 90~180 seconds, then since the start of the first 2 tasks, the remaining 2 tasks still start execution after 180 seconds.
So the start time of tasks happen every check_interval seconds.
Does anyone understand why my implementation of TaskMonitor affects the start time of celery tasks?
Thanks a lot!
This is the discussion thread in the celery github repo: https://github.com/celery/celery/discussions/9167
Above was my try, observation, and my problem.

Your celery task is not considered ended until its last thread (the monitoring thread) has ended.
